# Permissions to access to MS Graph API via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Question**

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to get report data via the MS Graph API `/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails`.
When I use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it works just fine, as long as I enable `Reports.Read.All` on the Modify permissions (Preview) tab.

But, when I try to do it with my script, I just get the error `"Calling principal does not have required MSGraph permissions Reports.Read.All"`

In all my searches, I can only find how to assign permissions to apps.
Is there some way to make it so I can do it from my script?

---

**My Script**

```
$azContext = Get-AzContext
$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(
    $azContext.Account,
    $azContext.Environment,
    $azContext.Tenant.Id,
    $null,
    [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never,
    $null,
    "https://graph.microsoft.com"
)

$params = @{
    Method  = "GET"
    Uri     = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails"
    Headers = @{
        Authorization  = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    }
}
Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

---

**Response**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code":"Authentication_MSGraphPermissionMissing",
    "message":"Calling principal does not have required MSGraph permissions Reports.Read.All",
    "innerError": {
      "date":"2021-10-19T01:18:36",
       "request-id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "client-request-id":"6b8cc3a3-b93b-44bb-b1d4-190c618aa52a"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to grant the admin consent and see, Reports.Read.All requires admin consent.

Comment: My question is how do I do admin consent for Reports.Read.All for my personal Azure account.

Comment: Hi, if any of the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally gave up on using the REST APIs and started using [`Microsoft.Graph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-beta) PowerShell Modules. I find the documentation pretty sparse, but at least it works for what I need. :)

```
Import-Module "Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins"
Import-Module "Microsoft.Graph.Users"
Import-Module "Microsoft.Graph.Groups"
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId  -Scopes "Directory.Read.All", "UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All" -ForceRefresh
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

$report = Get-MgReportCredentialUserRegistrationDetail
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> When I use Graph Explorer it works just fine, as long as I enable
> Reports.Read.All on the Modify permissions (Preview) tab.

Its because `Microsoft Graph Explorer` is a Enterprise Application of Microsoft which is present on every Azure AD tenant just you need to sign in and use it by providing the required permissions.

But when you are writing running your Powershell script it uses `Microsoft Azure Powershell` . You can verify it by checking the `access_token` received in [JWT Token](https://jwt.io/).So, you need to provide the `Reports.Read.All` API Permission to the same app in your tenant with appid : `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2` in Enterprise Application >> Permissions and grant the admin consent .After providing the required permissions only it will work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Another Way will be to create a App registration ,Create a client secret for it and then provide the `Reports.Read.All` API permission and use the below script:**

```
$TenantName = "tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"
$clientID = "d344e3xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-9c861d363244" # app registration clientId
$clientSecret = "fNc7Q~UNHBgv_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-PD"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
 
$Body = @{
    Grant_Type = "client_credentials"
    Scope = $Scope
    client_Id = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUri -Method POST -Body $Body

$Headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $($TokenResponse.access_token)"
        "Content-type"  = "application/json"
    }
$apiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $apiUri -Method GET
 
$response.value
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** In Some Tenants Microsoft Azure PowerShell might not be visible from portal , so in that case please use the above solution it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

For Authorization code flow, try something like this -

```
#region Auth1
#With User Interaction for Delegated Permission
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

Function Get-AuthCode {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width = 440; Height = 640 }
    $web = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width = 420; Height = 600; Url = ($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }

    $DocComp = {
        $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri        
        if ($Global:uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") { $form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() })
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

    $queryOutput = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($web.Url.Query)
    $output = @{}
    foreach ($key in $queryOutput.Keys) {
        $output["$key"] = $queryOutput[$key]
    }

    #$output
}

Get-AuthCode
#Extract Access token from the returned URI
$regex = '(?<=code=)(.*)(?=&)'
$authCode = ($uri | Select-string -pattern $regex).Matches[0].Value

Write-output "Received an authCode, $authCode"

$tokenBody = @{  
    Grant_Type    = "authorization_code"  
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
    Client_Id     = $clientId  
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
    code          = $authCode
    ressource     = $resource
}   

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenBody -ErrorAction STOP

#endregion Auth1
```

For delegated permissions use something like below -

```
$tokenBody = @{  
    Grant_Type = "password"  
    Scope      = "user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access"  
    Client_Id  = $clientId  
    username   =  $User
    password   = $pw
    resource  = $resource
}   

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenBody -ErrorAction STOP

#endregion Auth2
```

For Application permissions (using client credential flow) use something like this

```
$tokenBody = @{  
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
    Client_Id     = $clientId  
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
}   

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$Tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody  


#endregion Auth3
```

Despite what Method you have chosen, the tokenRepsonse Variable is holding our Key to Query against the Microsoft GRAPH API.

We want a list of all Teams in our Tenant, so this require propriate Application Permission. So for example- our Powershell to get a Full List of all Teams look like this -

```
$headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"
        "Content-type"  = "application/json"
    }

$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?`$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"  
$AllTeams = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Method GET).value
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the Auth1. Not sure what $Scope should be so I did `@( "user.read", "openid", "profile", "offline_access" )` 
But it just pops up a blank dialog. 

What am I missing?